# How to find nth data in python after special char?

Tags: python, split, mapreduce, bigdata

I have a file that contains some information in the line. I just want to print the words after the **last character ∑**.
How can I do this?

text:

```
App∑Category∑Rating∑Reviews∑Size∑Installs∑Type∑Price∑Content Rating∑Genres∑Last Updated∑Current Ver∑Android Ver
Photo Editor & Candy Camera & Grid & ScrapBook∑ART_AND_DESIGN∑4.1∑159∑19M∑10,000+∑Free∑0∑Everyone∑Art & Design∑7-Jan-18∑1.0.0∑4.0.3 and up
Coloring book moana∑ART_AND_DESIGN∑3.9∑967∑14M∑500,000+∑Free∑0∑Everyone∑Art & Design;Pretend Play∑15-Jan-18∑2.0.0∑4.0.3 and up
```

Code:

```
def mapper(_, line):
    words = line.split('∑')
```

Result:
[4.0.3 and up, 4.0.3 and up]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An efficient method is to use `rsplit` with a maxsplit of 1, and take the last item:

```
def mapper(_, line):
    last = line.rsplit('∑', maxsplit=1)[-1]
```

Note that this will default to the full line if there isn't the split character in the line.

If you want to ensure that there is a valid split:

```
def mapper(_, line):
    chunks = line.rsplit('∑', maxsplit=1)
    last = chunks[1] if len(chunks)==2 else None # or other default value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just use the index `[-1]` as follows:

```
def mapper(_, line):
    words = line.split('∑')
    print(words[-1])
```